# self excluding excecution of functions in django

Tags: python, django, concurrency, race-condition

i have a django model that has values stored in a json field.
but some of the values have to be unique, for that i have a function check_unique().
but this check fails if two users try to save the same value at the same time since when check_unique() runs neither of the values is stored in the database and then they are individually correct.
There is a way to avoid this behavior?
i tried avoiding this using trheadeing.Lock but apache runs in different processes and it does'nt work in that case.

Besides, i would like that the check would be at application level (in python) and not at database level.

the code looks like this:

```
semaphore.claim()
try:
   uniques = check_unique(self.answers)
   if not uniques:
      self.go_save()
      semaphore.release()
      return Response("All OK")
 except Exception as e:
      semaphore.release()
      return e
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at atomic requests in Django? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

Aas far as I know, if you make that transaction with the database atomic, it would not be able for the second user to save it to the database. What atomic does, basically, is that it will try to save the values to the database, but when it recognizes an exception, it will revert those changes to the database.

Another approach would be to create a custom validator, that checks the value twice. So once it will check to see if the value exists in the db, and then x seconds later (randomize that so both users won't be able to validate the exact same time). That way, if user 1 has already saved it to the database, the second check would see it and cancel the operation.

Finally, check out https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous. May be it does what you need!

Hope that helps.